# Replace data after a regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a log file with data I need to mask/replace.

#### Test file example

```
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-109(String to replace)
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-106(String to replace)
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-104(String to replace)
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-102(String to replace)
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-18(String to replace)
```

It has many more of the eTDYN-str, 01-110.

I need to find each instance, one per line, and replace all of the text directly after it.

I was trying something like

```
perl -pie 's/^(eTDYN-str-multi-\d\d:\s+).*/$1<removed pii data>/g;' logtest.txt
```

I know it would only work for two digit numbers after the text, but it's not even finding/replacing it.

Comment: The pattern is `eTDYN-str-multi-\d\d\d`, how can Perl find `eTDYN-str-multi-\d\d:\s+`?

Comment: For one thing, you anchored "eTDYN" to match at the string's beginning and it's not there.

Comment: could you show input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed to do something like:

```
sed 's/\(eTDYN-str-multi-[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*/\1<REPLACEMENT_STRING>/' <name of your test file>
```

This will match the literal "eTDYN-str-multi-" followed by one, two, or three digits, save that as "\1" and will match anything after that. Then it'll replace the matched string with "\1" (the saved portion and  of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is resolved, I'm posting a Perl solution for posterity:

First, the `-pie` flags are treated as `-p -ie` and not `-p -i -e` as you intended, because the -i flag takes an argument, the extension of the backup file for in-place editing. `-i` by itself disables the backup. But anyway:

```
$ pbpaste|perl -pe's/eTDYN-str-multi-\d{1,3}\K.*/<removed pii data>/'
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-109<removed pii data>
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-106<removed pii data>
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-104<removed pii data>
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-102<removed pii data>
20120910:181649:TID=000ef4:Add       :C155:E076:P:     eTDYN-str-multi-18<removed pii data>
```

Makes use of the `\K` or 'keep' escape, [documented in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions):

> For various reasons \K may be significantly more efficient than the equivalent `(?<=...)` construct, and it is especially useful in situations where you want to efficiently remove something following something else in a string. For instance

```
s/(foo)bar/$1/g;
```

> can be rewritten as the much more efficient

```
s/foo\Kbar//g;
```